# database synchronisation

Tags: database, synchronization

I have two databases at two different places, both databases are same with table name as well as fields. now I want to synchronise both database. Is there any java code or we can achieve that directly from mysql or sql ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to consider [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) as an option.

Comment: Is replication works on all mysql version ?
Is it works on version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I can do this if we have a main database (1st DB) and secondary one (2rd DB), and synchronise secondary DB when main DB changed.

when 1st DB change, you make a version number (which table change, at which row, column? and value?). the 2rd DB will check the version of it and update data for 2rd DB.

(you should reference the way that implement source control for complex situations)